# How to test child component method with Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, enzyme

I have a component like that:

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
</Parent>
```

and `<Child/>` component have a method `foo`. I want test the `foo` method but I don't know how to access it. I tried:

```
mount(<Parent><Child/></Parent>).props().children.foo
```

or

```
mount(<Parent><Child/></Parent>).children().foo
```

but both them are `undefined`. I can't use `.instance()` because it's not root. I can't mount `<Child/>` only because the `<Parent>` add something (react-router's `context.router`) on `context` and I need them when init `<Child/>`. Any idea with this?

Comment: It's seems this is still not possible or at least complicated: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/361

Comment: Test the react components lower down in the tree before working your way up. Also export an unwrapped version of your component for tests in order to remove the dependency of the component on react router.

Comment: +1 most annoying thing about writing react specs, I don't understand how you could write a spec framework for react and not have an easy way to access instances of child components. dumb.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
mount(<Parent><Child/></Parent>).find(Child).instance().foo
```

Comment: Instance can only be called on root.

Comment: how to import `Child` component

Answer (score 4):

I would consider writing tests for only your parent class, and then a separate test file to only test your child.

Once you have mounted you component using:

```
const component = mount(<Child>);
```

you then have access to it's methods using:

```
component.instance().methodname
```

You can then do stuff like override it with jest.fn() and test appropriately.

Comment: This is not possible anymore from React 16.x

Answer (score 4):

I prefer shallow mount over full mount from enzyme.

In conjunction with proxyquire to resolve child component (which you want to test) 
I do

```
wrapper.find('Child1').props().propName
```

And test it.

Or I use shallow

```
mount wrapper.dive()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is way different from how to test child components.

My first question is: Why are you checking if a child component has a specific method in the parent's component tests?

IMHO you need to have a test specific for this component and, then, in this test you check if the method exists.

Just to not leave without the answer, did you tried `.find(Child).instance().foo` ?

Comment: .instance() can only be called on the "root"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when trying to mock a function on an inner component within a MemoryRouter:

```
cont wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter><AvailabilityButtonWithRouter.WrappedComponent vetId={ vetId  } appointment={ availability } /></MemoryRouter>);
```

I ended up being able to mock the function like so:

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();    
wrapper.children(0).children(0).instance().reloadCurrentPage = mockFn;
```

Comment: Good, it helped me find a function in 3 level nested Item child component that rendered multiple times. Don't need the `0` argument, like `.children(0)`, but just `children()`. And when ready to find it, just `.first().getElement()` and props. My Example : `wrapper.find('Item').children().first().getElement()`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a handle on child function like the following, i was looking for the first child to call the function on -

```
const component = shallow(<Component />);
component.find(Child).first().getNode().props.someChildFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and I went through `mount` API by logging. In my use case, my child component(CommonStoresReactions) is wrapped with mobx `inject`.

```
const jsx = (
    <Provider {...stores}>
      <CommonStoresReactions>
        <div />
      </CommonStoresReactions>
    </Provider>
)
const wrapper = mount(jsx)
```

I want to test `clearStores` method in `CommonStoresReactions`. Below snippet worked for me.

```
wrapper
      .find(CommonStoresReactions)
      .instance()
      .wrappedInstance.clearStores()
```

Comment: .instance() can only be called on "root"

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme has an option for the `mount` API called `wrappingComponent` (and `wrappingComponentProps`) to wrap the mounted object inside another component for providing context, etc.

See https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md#mountnode-options--reactwrapper

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using [dive](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

```
wrapper.dive().props().propName
```

Answer (score 0):

With enzyme:

```
mount(<Parent><Child/></Parent>).childAt(0).instance().foo
```

There are valid reasons to access the child and call a method. If the parent is superficial and children have a consistent interface you can call methods without knowing which child it is, testing that all children have the correct interface, signature etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I find out is using shallow wrapper's `dive` method. Here is the doc: [enzyme dive doc](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

Remember if ur parent component use the fully rendering like `mount`, then the react wrapper itself doesnt have the dive method so u have to use shallow render.

Here is one example:

```js
let instance, child, diveChild;
describe('Test Parent child Child component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props} />);
    child = wrapper.find('Child');
    diveChild = child.dive();
    console.log(diveChild.instance());
  });

  test('Child get mounted', () => {
    expect(child.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(child.debug()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by [echoing @rnmalone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48690643/1028230) that you probably don't want to test a *function* on a child directly. That's not really unit testing, that's *integration* testing. You don't want to test your `foo` method.

That said, you may want to grab children to test their `bar` value and see if they received something you did to them by manipulating the parent. And since, if you `mount` at least (?), the children are fully instantiated, there's no reason to spy on a shim; you can go straight to the "real" child and test it.

Here's a test that does both. We do test a `foo` on a child, so to speak -- it's an event handler -- and then we test its `bar` value -- in this case that the proper child had a value set to match what we raised in the `foo` event.

---

#### Testing if `foo` sets `bar`

In this test, we've spun up a component we're testing (we were using [Preact](https://preactjs.com/) instead of React and [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm) in place of JSX; apologies if I don't clean this perfectly):

```
var wrapper = Enzyme.mount(
    <MyParentComponent
        myItemTypes={arrayTypes}
        mySelectedItem={someSelectedItem}
        onTabClicked={mySpy.onTabClicked}
    />
);
```

Now `MyParentComponent` has child components in its markup called `MyChildComponent`.

(This is its "live" code, returned by a functional component, and is not from a test file, to be overly clear.)

```
return <ul>
    {Object.keys(props.myItemTypes).map(function (key) {
        var isSelected = myItemTypes[key] === mySelectedItem;

        return 
            <MyChildComponent
                isSelected={isSelected}
                tabType={myItemTypes[key]}
                onTabClicked={props.onTabClicked}
            ></MyChildComponent>
        ;
    })}
</ul>;
```

So the parent component is, with respect to the `onTablClicked` event handler, basically just a passthrough.

Now I can spoof a click on a child item like this using [ReactTestUtils](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html):

```
var specificItem = wrapper
    .find('MyChildComponent')
    .findWhere((x) => x.props().tabType.value === newlySelectedTab.value);

if (specificItem) {
    var onTabClicked = lessonsTab.props().onTabClicked;
    TestUtils.act(function () {
        onTabClicked(newlySelectedTab);
    });
}

wrapper.update();
```

The nasty part here is that I registered that `onTabClicked` from this on the parent component:

`onTabClicked={mySpy.onTabClicked}`

That is, that `act` on the selected child will just call my spy, and my spy does this:

```
spyOn(mySpy, 'onTabClicked').and.callFake(function (tab) {
    wrapper.setProps({ mySelectedItem: tab });
});
```

That's problematic. We'll discuss that later.

Now I can run a test to see if the child's prop was updated.

```
it('should send the new selection value to the child component', function () {
    var allItems = wrapper.find(MyChildComponent);
    var selectedItem = navItems.findWhere((x) => x.props().isSelected);

    expect(selectedItem.props().settingsTab.value).toBe(newlySelectedTab.value);
});
```

---

#### But that really reduces to mock `foo` and real `bar`

Again, the weird part of doing that is the fake click on the child is really close to testing your mocks, which you shouldn't really do. (Reference is a powerpoint. [Click at your own risk](https://stepupsessions.com/assets/ING%20-%20Dev%20for%20Ops/Dev%20Lessons%20For%20Ops%20-%20Lesson%204%20-%20Automated%20testing%20-%20Unit,%20Integration%20&%20End-To-End.pptx).)

[image: powerpoint slide titled "Common testing mistakes & avoiding them" with a first point of "don't test your mocks (surprisingly common)"]

I could've just tested initial state setting like this:

```
it('should send the new selection value to the child component', function () {
    // Act 
    wrapper.setProps({ mySelectedItem: itemToSelect });
    wrapper.update();

    // Assert
    var allItems = wrapper.find(MyChildComponent);
    var selectedItem = navItems.findWhere((x) => x.props().isSelected);

    expect(selectedItem.props().tabType.value).toBe(itemToSelect.value);
});
```

... and that's *probably* good enough for whatever work you're doing. It reduces to nearly the same thing.

I guess the bonus is that you know the event handler is registered on the child, and that's something. Though we should probably *just* test that `foo` fired using `mySpy` on `MyParentComponent`, right? And then add a second test to see that the child value changes when the parent prop does.

So likely still [a code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) somewhere.