# How does one access state on a nested React component wrapped by an HOC?

Tags: react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I'm using [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/index.html), and we can actually use the [example](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setState.html#example) component given in the docs as a foundation for my question.

Let's assume this `<Foo />` component uses a `<Link>` component from ReactRouter and thus we need to wrap it in a `<MemoryRouter>` for testing.

Herein lies the problem.

```
it('puts the lotion in the basket', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Foo />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )

  wrapper.state('name') // this returns null! We are accessing the MemoryRouter's state, which isn't what we want!
  wrapper.find(Foo).state('name') // this breaks! state() can only be called on the root!
})
```

So, not exactly sure how to access local component state when using `<MemoryRouter>`.

Perhaps I'm performing an ignorant test? Is trying to get/set component state bad practice in testing? I can't imagine it is, as Enzyme has methods for getting/setting component state.

Just not sure how one is supposed to access the internals of a component wrapped in `<MemoryRouter>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245215/how-to-test-child-component-method-with-enzyme

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So it seems with the [latest release](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/releases/tag/enzyme%403.2.0) of Enzyme there is a potential fix for this issue of accessing state on a child component.

Let's say we have `<Foo>` (note the use of React Router's `<Link>`)

```
class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    bar: 'here is the state!'
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Link to='/'>Here is a link</Link>
    )
  }
}
```

> Note: The following code is only available in Enzyme v3.

Revisiting the test code, we are now able to write the following

```
it('puts the lotion in the basket', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Foo />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )

  expect(wrapper.find(Foo).instance().state).toEqual({
    bar: 'here is the state!'
  })
})
```

Using `wrapper.find(Child).instance()` we are able to access `Child`'s state even though it is a nested component. In previous Enzyme versions we could only access `instance` on the root. You can also call the `setState` function on the `Child` wrapper as well!

We can use a similar pattern with our shallowly rendered tests

```
it('puts the lotion in the basket shallowly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Foo />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )

  expect(wrapper.find(Foo).dive().instance().state).toEqual({
    bar: 'here is the state!'
  })
})
```

Note the use of [`dive`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) in the shallow test, which can be run on a single, non-DOM node, and will return the node, shallow-rendered.

---

Refs:

- https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/361
- https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1289
- https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3

Comment: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html Still it shows tells `Gets the instance of the component being rendered as the root node passed into mount()`, and as I am using `mount`, still unable to access the state of child component, tells `state` is not a function. My code is like:
```let wrapper = mount(<Parent />);
```

Comment: Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487409/how-to-access-child-component-state-and-lifecycle-methods-and-validate-in-react

Answer (score 2):

Thought it might be useful for you guys, as I stumbled upon this and have a fix.

In my case I have a component which is connected to redux.

```
class ComponentName extends Component {
...
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
...
 }
)(ComponentName );
```

connect() is obviously a HOC component. 
So how do we access the "ComponentName" here?

Very simple:

```
component
    .find(ComponentName)
    .children()
    .first()
    .props() // returns ComponentName's props
```

Comment: Amazed that worked, but is there a way to design the component for testing to avoid needing this?