# React - How to test a decorated class

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

how can I test a decorated component? 
I decorated a component using the react-tracking library, like:

```
@track((props) => ({category: 'EDIT', page: 
props.history.location.pathname}))
class EditTemplate extends React.Component<Props, State> {...}

export default EditTemplate;
```

When I try to test it like this:

```
it("test description", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<EditTemplate history={mockHistory}/>);
    expect(wrapper.prop("history")).toEqual("xyz");
    expect(wrapper.state("code")).toEqual("some value");
});
```

the prosp test works fine, but the state is always null! I tried using instance(), dive(), get(0), with the wrapper but the result it's always the same. If I remove the decorator, the test passes.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: what does decorator do?

Comment: adds the track information to the component. It's the react-tracking library

Comment: yes, missed that. so it's just ordinary HOC but used as decorator. don't see any magic there. have just played with example from docs and `wrapper.dive().state()` [definitely works](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w0v1717r?module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.spec.js&moduleview=1&previewwindow=tests)

Comment: it says that "state() can only be called on the root"... I created a function in the component that returns the state, and I got the state from that function directly and it works. I'd be nice to access to it without the workaround.

Comment: so have you finally dealt with checking `props` and only `state` is left to work at?  but do you really need accessing `state` directly? typically we call some callback prop or simulate some events and then just validate component's state through `.toMatchSnapshot()`. maybe it would be better to go this way.

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979735/how-does-one-access-state-on-a-nested-react-component-wrapped-by-an-hoc if it may help